# Android ESRI map how to get the latitude longitude from screen point

Tags: esri-maps, arcgis-android-api

I know we can get the `screenPoint` from the touched location on the ESRI map using this

```
val screenPoint = android.graphics.Point(motionEvent.x.roundToInt(), motionEvent.y.roundToInt())
```

And also we can get the `mapPoint` from the `screenPoint` using this

```
val mapPoint = mapView?.screenToLocation(screenPoint)
```

Now how do I get the latitude and longitude from these `screenPoint` or `mapPoint`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the `CoordinateFormatter` as below

```
val mapPoint = mapView?.screenToLocation(screenPoint)
            val toLatitudeLongitude = CoordinateFormatter.toLatitudeLongitude(mapPoint, CoordinateFormatter.LatitudeLongitudeFormat.DECIMAL_DEGREES, 4)
            val point = CoordinateFormatter.fromLatitudeLongitude(toLatitudeLongitude, spatialReference)
            val latitude = point.x
            val longitude = point.y
```

Reference: https://developers.arcgis.com/android/latest/java/sample-code/format-coordinates/